# Event from other class

Tags: vb.net

I have to "catch" an event from another class but I can't.
Project contains two forms: Form1 and Form2 and class params. Form 1 contain one button which have to change property value in class props. And Form2 have to know when props raises event.

Here is situation:

```
    ''Form1 code
Public Class Form1
Dim p As New params

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    p.demo = "mytry"
End Sub
End Class 

    ''Form2 code
Public Class Form2
Private WithEvents p As params

Private Sub pChanged(ByVal propertyName As String) Handles p.PropChanged
    MessageBox.Show(propertyName)
End Sub
End Class

    ''Class params code
Public Class params
Public Event PropChanged(ByVal propName As String)
Private _demo As String

Public Property demo() As String
    Get
        Return _demo
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _demo = value
        RaiseEvent PropChanged("demo")
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Problem is that sub pChanged in Form2 is never fired and have to be fired when property "demo" raises an event PropChanged.

How to get this working?

Comment: Have you used the debugger to confirm that `p.demo = "mytry"` is executed?

Comment: Yes it is. I put a breakpoint to raiseevent in params and it is executed soon after I press a button in form1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `params` variables and you are handling the wrong in `Form2` if you change the property in `Form1`.  You could handle the event in `Form2` and raise it again to handle it in `Form1`.

One here:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim p As New params
```

and one here

```
Public Class Form2
Private WithEvents p As params
```

Note that you have to use `WithEvents p As New params` also in `Form1` if you want to handle the event there.

Comment: I just want to handle event in Form2 and that I cannot reach. Can you give me a critical part of code for this?

Comment: @user973238: the problem is that the `params` variable that are you setting is in `Form1` and not in `Form2`. If you want to keep it in `Form1` but handle it's event in `Form2` you need to pass the instance of `Form1` to `Form2`.

Comment: It depends on what you really want to do.  You could   remove `params` from `Form1` and use it only in `Form2`. You could  set it's properties by creating a new public property in `Form2` that sets the `params` property. Then you could use this property from `Form1`. You should really use more meaningful names for your variables.

Comment: It is interesting that I can catch this event in public module but can't in form2! That behaviour I can use to make a workarround! Thanks Tim, I would use meaningfull names second time.